# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "echar un polvo"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Es frecuente en ambientes coloquiales decir *echar un polvo* para definir el acto sexual:

> ¡Estaban esos dos **echando un polvo** cuando apareció el marido de ella!

O similares. Es decir, por algún motivo se asocia *echar un polvo* con el encuentro carnal...

Y resulta que leo en Twitter:

> ECHAR UN POLVO es una expresión que deriva del siglo XVIII y se empleaba primero sin connotación sexual. Se refería a la costumbre de tomar el tabaco en polvo, en forma de RAPÉ, que se aspiraba por la nariz. Cuando los "raperos" sentían necesidad de tomar algo de tabaco, salían a ECHAR UN POLVO. Con el tiempo, parejas de tortolitos comenzaron a aprovechar la excusa de "echar un polvo" para dejar la reunión social y tener apasionados encuentros eróticos. De ahí, ECHAR UN POLVO pasó a denominar el encuentro sexual.
>
> <sub>Etimologías, @EtimosDirectos. [Twitter, 19 noviembre 2019](https://twitter.com/EtimosDirectos/status/1196684844337643520)</sub>

La historia parece tener sentido, pero tampoco se aporta ninguna referencia. Buscando en el DLE veo que

> [**rapé**](https://dle.rae.es/rap%C3%A9)
>   `Del fr. rapé 'rallado'.`
>
> 1. m. tabaco rapé.
>
> > [**tabaco rapé**](https://dle.rae.es/tabaco#EwWtRyv)
> >     1. m. tabaco de polvo, más grueso y más oscuro que el ordinario y elaborado con hoja cortada algún tiempo después de madurar.

El NTLLE da la primera entrada de *rapé* con este significado en 1803 Academia usual (texto tal cual):

> Tabaco de color negrusco, y cuyo polvo es algo grueso y graneado. Dixose asi por el instrumento y modo con que se molia.

Lo que sí vendría a confirmar que el rapé se aspiraba por la nariz. Pero el resto, ¿es cierto?

Answer (score 4):

Lo ideal sería encontrar un texto del siglo XIX o anterior en el que se jugara con el doble sentido de "echar un polvo" propuesto por la teoría. No he encontrado (aún) tal texto, pero las evidencias que encuentro apuntan a que así es.

En primer lugar, en 1737 el *Autoridades* definía lo siguiente:

> Un *polvo*. Se entiende por una tomadura de tabaco. Dícese assi, porque el tabáco está reducido à polvo.

Luego sí, la parte de *un polvo* se confirma. Y la hemeroteca de la Bilbioteca Nacional de España nos confirma que se usaba con el verbo *echar*:

> *No necesita canela el buen chocolate: el que guste de ella puede echar un polvo en la chocolatera al tiempo de batirlo para echarlo en la xícara.*
>
> **Semanario de agricultura y artes dirigido a los párrocos.** 19/1/1804, n.º 368, [página 6](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003351632&page=6&search=%22echar%20un%20polvo%22&lang=es).

Se entiende en este texto *echar un polvo* como "echar una pizca [de canela]". Sin embargo, la acepción de *polvo* en su sentido erótico no llega al diccionario hasta finales del siglo XX, concretamente hasta la edición de 1992. Esto puede ser debido a la reticencia de la RAE a introducir en su obra términos malsonantes (ese mismo año se añadió al diccionario la acepción vulgar de *follar*, ¿casualidad?). Tampoco era una expresión muy dada a ser usada en obras, pero afortunadamente para eso estaban las comedias teatrales. Por favor, ruego se reclinen en sus asientos y saquen las palomitas para leer el siguiente texto (NSFW):

> *PACA AVELLANA:
>
>   No me iré, que ya hasta el moño
>
>   inundada estoy de leche:
>
>   no me iré sin que se me eche
>
>   un polvo o más en el coño.
>
>   ¡Yo os adoro, y por mi vida
>
>   siento, y justo es que se entienda,
>
>   tras de oír tanta jodienda
>
>   no poder ser yo jodida!*
>
> *DON JUAN:
>
>   De tu afán ego te absolvo,
>
>   que no sé cómo he tenido
>
>   calma para haberte oído
>
>   sin haberte echado un polvo.
>
>   Tiéndete pues, y al avío,
>
>   del amor dulce retoño,
>
>   dame al momento tu coño.*
>
> *RITA MAMELLAS:
>
>   Eso no, que aquí está el mío.*
>
> Anónimo, "Don Juan Notorio: burdel en cinco actos y 2000 escándalos", 1874 (España).

No me extraña que el texto sea anónimo, imaginad lo que pudo ser esta obra en el siglo XIX...

Con esto ya sabemos que *un polvo* hacía referencia al tabaco en el siglo XVIII, y en general a cualquier cosa de la que se pudieran coger pizcas a principios del siglo XIX, pudiendo *echar un polvo de canela*, por ejemplo, y que hacia la segunda mitad del siglo XIX la frase *echar un polvo* ya tenía su sentido festivo. Lo que falta es la conexión entre ambos sucesos. Seguiré investigando por si pudiera encontrar ese texto que me falta para dar por cierta la conexión.

---

El blog de Alfred López recoge en [su entrada para la expresión](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/tag/don-juan-notorio-burdel-en-cinco-actos-y-2000-escandalos/) la historia del rapé como la más aceptada por los académicos, aunque recoge también otro posible origen con menos aceptación. Esta segunda teoría dice que provendría de una fórmula litúrgica que se popularizó en la frase *polvo somos, del polvo venimos, y en polvo nos convertiremos*. La parte de *del polvo venimos* sería la que dio origen a la acepción sexual de *polvo*. No es una teoría descabellada.